# OPENVINO-python, cannot import name 'IEPlugin' from 'openvino.inference_engine'

Tags: python, opencv, intel, openvino

I am trying to run a project developed with openvino 2019. I have version 2021 and I cannot downgrade to the old version. According to intel, the IENetwork and IEPlugin class has already been eliminated. What do you recommend for it to work?
I attach the repository: https://github.com/vyzboy92/people_detection_tracking-CPU/blob/master/multi_camera_people_detection.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhF5M.png)

Comment: How do you install it? by doing `pip install openvino`?

Comment: I installed openvino following the official documentation of openvino https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html
and I already have the openvino environment started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I realized in the [installation guide](https://docs.openvino.ai/2019_R3.1/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html), the version selection doesn't go below than `2020`, so use below answer.

You could install it on [their GitHub](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/releases/tag/2019_R3.1). Looking at the directories of the source code, it looks like the python library is at

```
openvino-2019_R3.1\inference-engine\ie_bridges\python\src\openvino
```

Try uninstalling the latest version and put the `openvino` folder located at `inference-engine\ie_bridges\python\src\` in your `site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so can I only install for versions later than 2020?

Comment: No, you **CAN** install the 2019 version on their GitHub, and put it in your `site-packages`

Comment: I am not a Linux user, so I don't know where the `site-packages` folder is.

Comment: It looks like in Linux, the `site-packages` path is located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just tested it and it worked fine. Thank you so much